# Is it possible to fine-tuning BERT by training it on multiple datasets? (Each dataset having it's own purpose)

Tags: nlp, bert, transformer, transfer-learning, finetuning

BERT can be fine-tuned on a dataset for a specific task. Is it possible to fine-tune it on all these datasets for different tasks and then be utilized for these tasks instead of fine-tuning a BERT model specific to each task?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible but the BERT model will lose its purpose. Each NLP task will have its optimal loss value. If many tasks are fine-tuned on the same model, the optimal loss function for all the tasks will not be reached.

Comment: Is this guaranteed? Transfer learning might help generalization instead of hindering it